# Jenkins: How to add a user which can take pull from git repo

Tags: git, jenkins, deployment

When I build one of my Jenkins Item which is linked with Github, I get this following error:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/hello-world-1/workspace
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/my_company/my_project.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/my_company/my_project.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > git config --local credential.username my_user_name # timeout=10
 > git config --local credential.helper store --file=/tmp/git2522812195492229039.credentials # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/my_company/my_project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision a05e77ea9c387fdecea800c3fd7a18c492dc393b (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f a05e77ea9c387fdecea800c3fd7a18c492dc393b
 > git rev-list a05e77ea9c387fdecea800c3fd7a18c492dc393b # timeout=10
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson158010815501794039.sh
+ cd /var/www/public_html/my_project
+ git pull origin master
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

What am I missing in it? 
How do I add user to run through Jenkins?

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <com.coravy.hudson.plugins.github.GithubProjectProperty plugin="github@1.15.0">
      <projectUrl>https://github.com/my-company/my-projetc/</projectUrl>
      <displayName></displayName>
    </com.coravy.hudson.plugins.github.GithubProjectProperty>
  </properties>
  <scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@2.4.1">
    <configVersion>2</configVersion>
    <userRemoteConfigs>
      <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
        <url>https://github.com/my-company/my-project.git</url>
        <credentialsId>ca9508ae-c502-405b-8d08-120435a3901b</credentialsId>
      </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
    </userRemoteConfigs>
    <branches>
      <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        <name>*/master</name>
      </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
    </branches>
    <doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
    <submoduleCfg class="list"/>
    <extensions/>
  </scm>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers>
    <com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubPushTrigger plugin="github@1.15.0">
      <spec></spec>
    </com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubPushTrigger>
  </triggers>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders>
    <hudson.tasks.Shell>
      <command>cd /var/www/public_html/my_project
git pull origin master
composer install</command>
    </hudson.tasks.Shell>
  </builders>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
```

I added user jenkins to different groups. Also, on the group to which my project folder belongs to. 
What could be the exact issue here?

Answer (score 0):

The connection with Github seems OK.

After the Git pull done by the Git SCM plugin, are you trying to jump to this folder?

```
cd /var/www/public_html/my_project
```

And next do a:

```
git pull origin master
```

Jenkins seems to not have the permission in this folder and I'm not sure this is the target folder where you want to pull your code.

Comment: I guess that's a permission problem. How do I add a specific system user to jenkins for running this job.

Comment: It says, started with user anonymous.

Comment: Yes the job has been started by an anonymous user, but when the jenkins process is running on your machine, it's with a jenkins user.

Comment: So, I need to add Jenkins to a specific group?

Comment: I added jenkins user to that group. But, it's the same.

Comment: If you can share with us your job config.xml file or some screen copies, it can help :)

Comment: How can I get config.xml? I am new to Jenkins.

Comment: It should be this file: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/hello-world-1/config.xml

Comment: Added the config.xml

Comment: Thanks for the config.xml file. As I said, you are trying to pull the Git code in this folder (/var/www/public_html/my_project). Because it's not the job working folder, your user don't have the relevant permission to write (I think). And second problem, your folder is maybe not a Git folder. One solution should be to use "/var/www/public_html/my_project" as a custom workspace of your job and to give the relevant permissions to the jenkins user.